# Regex multiline replace

Tags: python, regex

So I have this:

```
z='===hello  
there===,  
how are ===you===?'
```

And I want to be:

```
z='<b>hello  
there<\b>,  
how are <b>you<\b>?'
```

I tried doing this:

```
z = re.sub(r"\={3}([^\$]+)\={3}", r"<b> \\1 </b>", z, re.M)
```

And it works sort of but I got this instead:

```
z='<b>hello  
there===,  
how are ===you<\b>?'
```

I'm still new to this but I believe it's the `^` and `$` that makes it match the beginning and the end of the string. So how do I change it so it matches the ones in the middle?

Comment: Use 4 spaces or <CTRL>-<K> To indent code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
re.sub(r"\={3}([^\$]+?)\={3}", r"<b> \\1 </b>", z, re.M)
```

Copy from python doc[Click Here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html):

> `*?, +?, ?? The '*', '+', and '?' qualifiers are all greedy; they match as much text as 
>       possible. Sometimes this behaviour isn’t desired; if the RE <.*> is matched against 
>       '<H1>title</H1>', it will match the entire string, and not just '<H1>'. Adding '?' after the
>        qualifier makes it perform the match in non-greedy or minimal fashion; as few characters as 
>       possible will be matched. Using .*? in the previous expression will match only '<H1>'.`

Comment: Please explain why this fixes the OPs problem, so he knows in the future. (It's because +? is lazy and matches as few characters as possible, so it stops at the first `<\b>` not the last `<\b>`)

Comment: Oh I see. And it worked! It also fixed another problem I had so thanks!